# Error "name 'app' is not defined"

Tags: python, web, flask

Cuando intento correr tanto en cmd de windows 10 como en Visual Studio Code este código:

```
from flask import Flask 

app == Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello world'

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run()
```

me sale:

> NameError: name 'app' is not defined

¿Por qué no se define `app`?

Comment: Hola Alex, bienvenido a [es.so]. Es un simple error tipográfico , es `app = Flask (__name__)` no `app == Flask (__name__)`. Operador de asignación (`=`) y no de igualdad (`==`).

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

El operador `==` sirve para comparar. Para asignar una variable, debes usar el operador `=`.

En tu caso `app = Flask (__name__)`.